# SNMP trap to IPv6 address

Tags: windows, snmp, snmp-trap

Is anybody aware of (windows) utility which can send SNMP traps to IPv6 addresses?

I've tried trapgen but it seems it's not able to work with IPv6 addresses.
Also there is net-snmp windows port but it's a real pain to use it for sending traps. For me it didn't work at all. It always failed with "Cannot find module (TRAP-TEST-MIB):".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal usage using Net-SNMP's snmptrap for sending a SNMPv2c trap:

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public 'udp6:[::1]:162' 0 linkUp.0
```

Answer (score -2):

First, I can confirm net-snmp should work fine for IP v6. It only takes time to configure it, which is really painful for first time users. You may spend more time on its documentation.

Another way is to write your own, but that of course takes more time.